Trouble Adding Metadata to Seurat object
I am trying to add additional metadata to my Seurat object. The problem is that the methods I'm using (merge, left_join, full_join, AddMetaData, etc.) change the dimensions of my metadata or simply do not work. The errors I am receiving using either method is:

Warning: Cannot add more or less meta data without cell names
Detected an unexpected many-to-many relationship     between`x`and`y`. ℹ Row 1 of `x`matches multiple rows in`y`. ℹ     Row 4518236 of `y`matches multiple rows in x. ℹ If a many-to-    many relationship is expected, set relationship = "many-to-    many"\\  to silence   this warning\

So far I have tried:
1.) MANIPULATING METADATA AFTER SEURAT OBJECT CREATION:
CONTEXT: the following code below is me reading in my files, creating a seurat object (sobj), and trying to manipulate the metadata to incorporate 1 other metadata file called "mapping". The Goal is to get the individual's sex, genotype, and diagnosis incorporated into the metadata before differential testing.
`barcodes <- synGet("syn23554294", downloadLocation="~/Downloads")
genes <- synGet("syn23554293", downloadLocation="~/Downloads")
mtx <- synGet("syn23554292", downloadLocation="~/Downloads")
metadata <- synGet("syn23554294", downloadLocation="~/Downloads")
counts <- ReadMtx(mtx = mtx$path, cells = barcodes$path, features = genes$path, feature.column = 1, skip.cell = 1, skip.feature = 1)
sobj <- CreateSeuratObject(counts, meta.data = metadata) # works fine`
head(metadat_aug16)
dim(metadata_aug16) # 74153    16
dim(sobj) # 28781 172659
These dimensions obviously do not match up!
head(sobj)
SOBJ: Seurat Object

2.) MANIPULATING DATA BEFORE CREATING SEURAT OBJECT
CONTEXT: I also tried extracting the metadata from Seurat as a dataframe, editing it with the info I needed, then resubmitting 'm' back as the metadata for the Seurat object. This works for the following code, but then I don't know how to go back and add even more information about the clinical info (sex, genotype, etc) especially when each individual and their cells are represented more than once in the metadata object / dataframe.
m <- as.data.frame(sobj@meta.data) # make into df and test seurat after
head(m) m$cell <- rownames(m) # save rownames (cells) as cell column
m$barcode <- substr(m$cell, 21, 36) # make barcode column
head(m)
dim(m) # 172659      5
dataframe called 'm':

**Can anyone help me find a way to do this? **
I tried lots of manipulations using dplyr and Seurat "AddMetaData" and get errors each time.

Please read How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and How do I format my code blocks?.

Here's a few reasons why you may have been encountering that error:

The length of the vector(s) containing the info you tried adding might not have matched the number of rows (cells) in the metadata
The way you tried adding the new infor to the metadata may have been set up incorrectly, especially if you attempted to add multiple columns using a dataframe/matrix.

I can't say for sure because the code you posted does not include examples of your attempts to add the new info to the metadata. Also, it appears you may have mixed up #1 & #2 of your context section, the code you included in #1 looks like it's related to things you did before seurat object creation and the code in #2 looks related to things you tried after creating the seurat object.
From the code you provided though, I noticed that your dataframe called "metadat_aug16" had 74153 cells, but the metadata dataframe called "m" had 172659 cells. I think this is a clue that indicates the ways you tried adding the metadata were likely not executed correctly. Either that or the metadata in "metadat_aug16" came from a seurat object that was created using a count matrix with a different number of cells to the one used to create the "sobj" seurat object.
Also, it's to be expected that the output of dim(sobj) would not match the output of dim(metadata_aug16) because dim(sobj) is giving you the dimensions of the default assay, which contains the count matrix (28781 genes vs 172659 cells). To get the dimensions of the metadata within sobj, you'd run:
dim(sobj@meta.data)

Adding New Metadata to a Seurat Object
With all of that out of the way, below are some examples of how to add new metadata to a seurat. You may have already fixed this problem since you posted it a couple months ago, but I think it might still be helpful for others to see.
Using a string
If the new data values should be the same for all the cells, you can just supply a string. For instance, if you want to add a column called "Sex" with the value of "female" to metadata of a seurat object called "sobj", you can run:
# Option 1 
sobj <- AddMetaData(sobj, "female", col.name = "Sex")

# Or

# Option 2
sobj$Sex <- "female"

Both of those commands will create a column called "Sex" with values of "females" for all cells.
Using a Vector
Now let's say you have a vector called "geno" containing genotype information you'd like to add to the metadata of sobj. Before adding the new data, verify that the length of geno exactly matches the number of rows in the metadata data frame within the seurat object:
identical(length(geno), nrow(sobj@meta.data))

If that command returns TRUE, you can run:
# Option 1 
sobj <- AddMetaData(sobj, geno, col.name = "Genotypes")

# Or

# Option 2
sobj$Genotypes <- geno

Using a Data Frame
If you want to use a dataframe to add multiple new columns to the metadata of the seurat, the following are some ways of doing so:
# First check that the data frame has the same number of rows as the metadata dataframe

identical(nrow(df), nrow(sobj@meta.data)) # TRUE

#########################################################################################

# Example 1
# If you want the new column names in the seurat to be the same as they are in the 
# data frame you're using

cnames <- col.names(df)

for (col in cnames) {
  sobj <- AddMetaData(sobj, 
                      df[ , col], 
                      col.name = col)
}

#########################################################################################

# Example 2
# If you want the new column names in the seurat to be different

cnames.in.df <- c("genos", "p.ribo")
new.cnames <- c("Genotype","Percent.Ribo")

for (i in 1:2) {
  sobj <- AddMetaData(sobj, 
                      df[ , cnames.in.df[i]], 
                      col.name = new.cnames[i])
}

Ensuring the New Data Goes to the Right Cells
I think I should also mention that just because the length/#rows of the object you're using is the same as the number of cells in the seurat object, does not mean you should just add the data to the seurat. If you have the cell IDs in the dataframe that contains the new metadata, you should verify that they are in the same order as they are in the seurat. Below is how you can check:
ids.in.df <- df$cellIDs
ids.in.seurat <- row.names(sobj@meta.data)

identical(ids.in.df, ids.in.seurat)

If you get FALSE, it could mean the IDs in the data frame are not in the same order as they are in the seurat object or it could mean the IDs are formatted/labeled differently in the data frame. Run the following commands to check if it's just a problem of the order being different:
# Get the unique IDs in the df and the IDs in the seurat

unique.ids.in.df <- unique(df$cellIDs)
ids.in.seurat <- row.names(sobj@meta.data)

identical(length(unique.ids.in.df), length(ids.in.seurat)) # Should be TRUE
identical(sort(unique.ids.in.df), sort(ids.in.seurat)) # Should be TRUE

If you determine that the order of the IDs in the data frame is different, you can either sort its rows so that the IDs are in the same order as they are in the seurat (assuming the IDs in the seurat are sorted), or you could just run the following to ensure the data in the df gets matched with the right cells in the seurat:
# Create a new empty column in the seurat

sobj <- AddMetaData(sobj, 
                    NA, 
                    col.name = "Percent.Ribo")
  
# Make the row.names of df to be the cell IDs to make things a bit simpler

df$cellIDs -> row.names(df)
  
# For each cell ID in df, place the data from df in the row of sobj that matches the same ID

for (cell in row.names(df)) {
  df[cell, "p.ribo"] -> sobj@meta.data[which(row.names(sobj@meta.data) == cell),
                                       "Percent.Ribo"]
  }

